# Grid Refresh using knockout js

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0, knockout-mvc

I am very new in knockout js and have been trying to refresh the Grid using knockout.
here is my view model

```
var GridViewModel = function () {
    var _this = {};



    _this.mainData = ko.observableArray();

  _this.DataFromServer= function()
    {
        var _transactions = $.getJSON('/data/getData', '', function (response) {
            if (response) {

                var results = ko.observableArray();
                _this.mainData.removeAll();
                results = response.mainData;
                for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                    _this.mainData.push(results[i]);
                };

            }
        });
  }

ko.applyBindings(_this);
    _this.DataFromServer();
    return _this;

}


var viewModel = GridViewModel();
```

Above code works fine and binds the data from server to grid but I am not sure how to bind this again after every 10 secs

I have been using the setInterval after Viewmodel call like this

```
 var viewModel = GridViewModel();

 setInterval(new GridViewModel(), 10000);
```

but this is not working. please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind , found the solution. Moved the AJAX method out of ViewModel and called it seperatly during AJAX calls.